# Apply function to permutations of lists of arguments

Tags: python

I have the need to take a function of n parameters and n lists of values and apply the function to each possible permutation of arguments. I have looked in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and none of the functions are quite right. The following is my attempt. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
def CrossReference(f, *args): 
   result = []
    def inner(g, *argsinner):
        rest = argsinner[1:]
        a = argsinner[0]
        if type(a) is not list:
            a = [a]
        for x in a:
            h = partial(g, x)         
            if len(rest) > 0:
                inner(h, rest)
            else:        
               result.append(h())        
    inner(f, args)
    return result
```

Here is my example test and error:

```
def sums(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z

CrossReference(sums, [1,2,3], 4, [5,6,7])
```

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, 
in    File "", line 13, 
in CrossReference   File "", line 12, in inner
TypeError: sums() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: what the expected output???

Comment: Your traceback appears to be incomplete.

Comment: I can't follow your code at all, but here's a thought: load your lists of values into the function, then use some `permutation` function to generate all permutations of `0:(j-1)` and use the output as your order of indices for each input.

Comment: ok, fixed traceback and modified code to return a list of results

Comment: What you have looks too complicated to me and suggest divide and conquer by getting a list of the permutations of the args (or do you want permutations of the values elements of the args if they are lists?) first and then run f() on each of them. In python permutations of a list can be obtained using itertools.permutations(list[x,y,z]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you call your `inner` function. You define your function header as:

```
def inner(g, *argsinner):
```

But you call your function like:

```
inner(f, args)
```

And:

```
inner(h, rest)
```

This means that you will end up with a single tuple (monotuple?) containing the tuple of your args. You can either change your function definition to:

```
def inner(g, argsinner):
```

Or change your calling to:

```
inner(h, *rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sums(x,y=0,z=0):
   return x+y+z

def apply(fn,*args):
    for a in args:
        try:
           yield fn(*a)
        except TypeError:
           try:
              yield fn(**a)
           except TypeError:
              yield fn(a)

print list(apply(sums,[1,2,3], 4, [5,6,7]))
```

is one way you might do it (not the only way though)